# The relationship between $\|A^n\|,\|e^{tA}\|$ and its spectral radius and spectral abscissa

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

Define the **spectral radius** of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$ $\rho(A)=\max\limits_i|\lambda_i|$, where $\lambda_i$ is $A$'s eigenvalue; the **spectral abscissa** $\alpha(A)=\max\limits_i \Re(\lambda_i)$.

Prove

1. $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\|A^n\|=0\iff \rho(A)<1$
2. $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\|e^{tA}\|=0\iff \alpha(A)<0$

Comment: One direction is straightforward using eigenvectors. The other direction is straightforward using the Jordan form.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks, finally I figured it out :)